# Will the 'split test' work for right splits, and not only middle splits?

Tags: splits

I really want to get my right splits so does the 'split test' also work for right? or is it only for the middle? I have been trying to get my splits for a while and the closest I get is my splits for one day then it hurts my legs and I lose it, I do the 'pillow exercise' to get them, is that a good idea? because it gets me very close, I've been doing warm ups and cool downs too, but I can never keep my splits so would the 'split test' work for my right splits??

Comment: Could you please describe what the "split test" and "pillow exercise" are?

Comment: The "Split test"  is probably the one at http://www.fightingarts.com/reading/article.php?id=12.